# lxml clean breaks href attribute

Tags: lxml

```
import lxml.html.clean as clean
cleaner = clean.Cleaner(style=True, remove_tags=['div','span',], safe_attrs_only=['href',])
text = cleaner.clean_html('<a href="http://жк-сочи.рф/">link</a>')
print text
```

prints

```
<a href="http://%C3%90%C2%B6%C3%90%C2%BA-%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%91%C2%87%C3%90%C2%B8.%C3%91%C2%80%C3%91%C2%84/">link</a>
```

how to get:

```
<a href="http://жк-сочи.рф/">link</a>
```

i.e href in normal encoding?

Comment: try lxml.html.tostring(text , encoding="ascii")

Answer (score 1):

`clean` does the right thing -- the string in parentheses should be properly encoded, and the seemingly garbled thing is the proper encoding.

You might not know, but kyrillic domain names don't exist -- there's a complex system to map these to "allowed" characters.